# Multiple If-else statement results

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How do I set up a if statement for multiple answers rather than conditions?

So for my example, I want to say that if `i` equal 0, then `a` and `b` will have unique answers.

```
df is a dataframe something like:

0 d 8
0 d 9
0 t 7
1 q 7
0 u 8
0 r 5
1 s 3

for c in range(len(df.index)):
    for i in df.iloc[[c]],0]:
        if i == 0:
            a = 12
            b = 'up'
OUT.write('%i,%s,'%(a,b))
```

error is: NameError: name 'a' is not defined

I have tried:

```
for c in range(len(df.index)):
    for i in df.iloc[[c]],0]:
        if i == 0:
            a = 12; b = 'up'
```

and

```
for c in range(len(df.index)):
    for i in df.iloc[[c]],0]:
        if i == 0:
            a = 12 and b = 'up'
```

Comment: ok and what is the problem with what you have written?

Comment: It just doesn't work. i call up the variable later, and it's not defined.

Comment: Looping over `pandas` data is very inefficient, in fact, the whole point of `numpy` and `pandas` is doing vectorized operations.

Comment: Have you tried running your code?  `a = 12 and b = 'up'` will give a syntax error.  `a = 12; b = 'up'` is ugly.

Comment: If the problem is that the syntax is ugly, then a, b = 12, 'up' will work

Comment: If you refer to `a` and `b` later and they are not defined then perhaps `i` never was equal to `0`.  Or `a` and `b` are being defined in another scope.

Comment: I think it would be best if you could post example input and example output data, that way we could show you how to do this efficiently with `pandas`.

Comment: @MasonJ. if you're calling a variable outside of the scope it was defined in it will be undefined. define `a` and `b` as `None` outside of your loop

Comment: My goal was to simplify my script. I originally had multiple if statements, but wanted to see if I could combine it into one since several statements share the same conditions, in this case, i = 0 in column 0

Comment: there's also the fact that if `a` and `b` are also part of the global scope then there might be some confusion as to what value is called when (I just saw that @StevenRumbalski had addressed this previously)

Comment: well, your code works for me if I just do print(a), and replace `df.iloc[[c]],0]` for `df.iloc[[c],0]`

Answer (score 2):

Lets suppose you have the following data-set in pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['variable', 'a', 'b'])
df.variable = np.random.choice(range(5), size=10)

print(df)
```

The output is as follows:

```
  variable   a   b
0   0   NaN NaN
1   4   NaN NaN
2   0   NaN NaN
3   3   NaN NaN
4   4   NaN NaN
5   0   NaN NaN
6   3   NaN NaN
7   3   NaN NaN
8   4   NaN NaN
9   0   NaN NaN
```

Now you can change the items in 'a' and 'b' as follows

```
df.loc[df.variable == 0, 'a'] = 12
df.loc[df.variable == 0, 'b'] = "up"
print(df)
```

the output:

```
    variable    a   b
0   0   12  up
1   4   NaN NaN
2   0   12  up
3   3   NaN NaN
4   4   NaN NaN
5   0   12  up
6   3   NaN NaN
7   3   NaN NaN
8   4   NaN NaN
9   0   12  up
```

Answer (score 2):

As alternative to `df.loc` used by Khalil Al Hooti you might consider using `np.where` in the following way

```
df["a"] = np.where(df.variable==0, 12, df["a"])
df["b"] = np.where(df.variable==0, "up", df["a"])
```

On my experiments looks a faster solution.

**Update**

[image]